# Can some of the case of this congruence be solvable? And what is the general way to solve this if it is solvable?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$a^m$ congruence to 1 (mod n)

where a and n is not a coprime and m is an integer.

How do you prove it if it is not solvable?

Comment: what do you know about the solvability of linear congruence, $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ when $\gcd(a,n)\gt 1$ ?

Comment: is $ax$ always congruence to multiple of gcd(a,n)? @ganeshie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(a,n)$. Then (assuming that $m$ is a positive integer) $a^m-kn$ is a multiple of $d$ for every $k\in\Bbb Z$. But $a^m\equiv 1\pmod n$ implies that $a^m-1=jn$ for some $j\in\Bbb Z$. This means that $d$ divides $1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Claim:* Units modulo $n$ are exactly the integers that are coprime to $n$.

If $a^m\equiv1\mod n\enspace(m>1)$, $a$ is a unit, with inverse $a^{m-1}$, hence $a$ and $n$ must be coprime.

*Proof of claim:*
If $a$ and $n$ are coprime, we have a Bézout's identity:$\,ua +kn=1$, hence, modulo $n$: $\,ua\equiv 1$.

Conversely, if there exists an integer $u$ such that $\,ua\equiv 1$, it means there exists $k\in \mathbf Z$ such that $ua=1+kn$, whence $ua-kn=1$, which is a Bézout's identity between $a$ and $n$.

*Note:* If $a$ and $n$ are not coprime, $a$ is a zero divisor modulo $n$. Indeed, let $d=\gcd(a,n)\enspace (d>1)$,  $a=da'$, $n=dn'$. Then $n'\not \equiv 0\mod n$, but
$$an'=a'dn'=a'n\equiv 0\mod n.$$